# Pagination custom post types outside loop

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

Because of speed / SEO reasons I'd like to load my custom post types as pagination ([1][2][3][4] etc). I have a page called **apps** and load all custom posts from apps.

I'm using currently this code to load all posts:

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => array( 'apps' ) ) );

$i=0;
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    if ($i%3==0) echo '

    <div class="row">

    ';

      echo '

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 app-wrapper">

                <div class="col-md-12 app-detail">              
            <a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '">';
      echo the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'app-icon'));      
      echo '<h2 class="center">'; the_title(); echo '</h2></a>';

            foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
            if (cat_is_ancestor_of(3, $childcat)) {
            echo '<h3 class="sub">';
            echo $childcat->cat_name . '</h3>';
            }}     


            echo '<p>';
            echo excerpt(25);
            echo '</p>';


      echo '';

          echo '<p><a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '" class="btn wide btn-view" >Bekijk project</a></p></div></div>';


    if ($i%3==2) echo '</div>'; 
    $i++;
endwhile;
?>
```

I'd like to load max 9 posts and then use pagination.

Comment: Use the [site search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=pagination+custom+queries). This issue has been handled many times :-)

Comment: Thanks Pieter, but still I can't get it working as most talk about single.php but this is a page.php.

Comment: Check [this example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query). If this does not work, let me know